# Download using gsutil

Tags: gsutil

I was using gsutil to download a trace file from google storage.
The command I used was:

gsutil/gsutil cp gs://clusterdata-2011-1/task_usage/part-00499-of-00500.csv.gz ./

But I got an error:

GSReponseError: Status=404, code=NoSuchKey, reason=Not Found.

However I used ls command in gsutil and the file existed.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Could you update your gsutil (gsutil update) to v3.21 and try again?

Comment: Thanks. After so many days and I try again. It just works. And the version is 3.21. I forgot the version I used last time. So I don't know whether the version was the problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works finally. The reason may be gsutil version or that the last time the server wasn't working.

Comment: This was a known bug in the recent object versioning code that was fixed in v3.21 of gsutil. Chances are you were using an older version of gsutil.